# Data not saving on Firebase & onComplete not being triggered

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I have the following Classes on my android studio project. NewTraineeActivity and Trainee classes. I am registering the data of a trainee on the Firebase real-time database.

This is what the Trainee class looks like:

```
public class Trainee {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private double height;
private String gender;
private String email;
private String nationality;

public Trainee(String firstName, String lastName, int age, double height, String gender, String email, String nationality) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.email = email;
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}
```

}

This is the NewTraineeActivity

```
public class NewTraineeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText firstNameEditText, lastNameEditText, ageEditText, heightEditText,
        genderEditText, emailEditText, nationalityEditText;
private ImageView profileImageView;

private Spinner genderSpinner;

private Button registerTraineeButton;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_trainee);

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);


    if (user == null) {
        // User is not authenticated, redirect to login or handle appropriately
        Toast.makeText(this, "User not authenticated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("trainees").child(user.getUid());

    // Initialize UI elements
    firstNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.firstNameEditText);
    lastNameEditText = findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText);
    ageEditText = findViewById(R.id.ageEditText);
    heightEditText = findViewById(R.id.heightEditText);
    genderSpinner = findViewById(R.id.genderSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.gender_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    genderSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    nationalityEditText = findViewById(R.id.nationalityEditText);
    profileImageView = findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
    registerTraineeButton = findViewById(R.id.registerTraineeButton);

    registerTraineeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("NewTraineeActivity", "Register button clicked"); // Log to check if the button click event is registered
            registerTrainee();
        }
    });
}

private void registerTrainee() {
    Log.d("NewTraineeActivity", "Registration Started"); // Log to check if the button click event is registered
    String firstName = firstNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String lastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    int age = Integer.parseInt(ageEditText.getText().toString().trim());
    double height = Double.parseDouble(heightEditText.getText().toString().trim());
    String gender = genderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String nationality = nationalityEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    // Create a Trainee object with the collected data
    Trainee trainee = new Trainee(firstName, lastName, age, height, gender, email, nationality);

    // Push the trainee object to the Firebase database
    databaseReference.push().setValue(trainee).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Registration successful, navigate back to Main Activity
                Log.d("NewTraineeActivity", "Registered"); // Log to check if the button click event is registered
                Toast.makeText(NewTraineeActivity.this, "Trainee registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewTraineeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {
                // Registration failed, handle the error
                Exception e = task.getException();
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e("NewTraineeActivity", "Registration failed: " + e.getMessage());
                } else {
                    Log.e("NewTraineeActivity", "Registration failed with no exception.");
                }
                Toast.makeText(NewTraineeActivity.this, "Failed to register trainee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is my firebase realtime database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This is the realtime database data

[image: This is the realtime database data]

In addition this is my logcat when I click the register trinee button i dont see the data being registered nor the onComplete on line 100 on new trainee class being triggered. this is the only log i see [image]

What is the possible solution here. I have ries making sure my internet is connected the refrence is correct, and exceptions are handeled

Comment: Add an `onFailureListener` as well and log the message. It will help to identify the cause behind this.

Comment: @PawanHarariya Firebase Realtime Database's push() method doesn't have an onFailure listener. It primarily deals with asynchronous operations, so you either the onComplete callbacks when the operation succeeds or an exception in the onComplete callbacks when it fails. The problem for me is the onComplete is not triggered which means it is not failing or succeeding

Comment: Have you checked logcat for any exceptions?

Comment: Is any of the Log or Toast messages displayed? Please respond using @AlexMamo